# Chrome Extension: Send chrome rich notifications via Websocket

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, websocket

I'm trying to use chrome.notifications API with Websocket in order to send rich notifications via Websocket. I have never work with Websocket before so I really don't know if this is the way to accomplish that:

I have changed my manifest in order to use the background.js and change to persistent true in order for WebSocket to work:

```
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["libraries/jquery-3.5.1.min.js", "scripts/background.js"],
    "persistent": true
  },
```

Then, I'm implementing Websocket on my background.js. The part that is confusing to me is that in theory, I have to use sendMessage to send the notification structure and at the same time listen to that message to create the notification on the same file (background.js). This is my background.js file:

```
//WebSocket
const socket = new WebSocket(
  'url that works'
);
$(function () {
  // Connection opened
  socket.addEventListener('open', function (event) {
    console.log('ws opened');
    socket.send('Hello Server!');
    //Sending The Notification Message
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage('', {
      type: 'notification',
      options: {
        title: 'Just wanted to notify you',
        message: 'How great it is!',
        iconUrl: '/icon.png',
        type: 'basic'
      }
    });
  });

  socket.addEventListener('close', function (event) {
    console.log('ws closed');
  });

  socket.addEventListener('error', function (event) {
    console.log('ws error');
    console.log(event);
  });

  // Listen for messages
  socket.addEventListener('message', function (event) {
    console.log('Message from server ', event.data);
    //Creating The Notification: Won't Show Up
    chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((data) => {
      if (data.type === 'notification') {
        chrome.notifications.create('', data.options);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

As you can see I'm trying to send a message with the notification structure on the socket.addEventListener('open'...) and then create the notification on the socket.addEventListener('message'...) part, maybe this is just totally wrong (as I said before I'm a total newbie when it comes to WebSocket. The result of this code is that I can see the console.log on the background page console but I never get the notification to work. Any help will be really appreciated.